# Refresh webdrivers on reload selenium

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver

I am using 32bit IE Webdriver and Selenium 2.0 and IE9 (VS2010 vb.net Test project) . I have to switch between tab (tables) and the contents within the tab is dynamically loaded upon clicking tab. in this case even thou using F12 i can find controls and frame but webdriver cannot find it. I guess the web driver is not getting refreshed on reloads ?

Just noticed that the frame src is set dynamically instead of the whole page load. All i need to set is the src of the frame. Can't get it to work it throws unexpected error??

```
   Dim navPath As String = "SomeDocument.aspx?txtCallingMode=witness&intEventID=&sCopyDefPCDConsultation=N&intCaseID=378"
                                                                           Dim jse As IJavaScriptExecutor = CType(Driver, IJavaScriptExecutor)
                                                                           jse.ExecuteScript("document.getElementById('framePage').src=" + navPath + ";")
```

Comment: Publish some code, and the URL of the web-page that you are trying to control (or at least the relevant piece of HTML in it).

Comment: You might be missed to handle the delay timing. Did you polled the frame before accessing it ? Which technique you have used to achieve this ?

Comment: Yes i have wait for 30 sec

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If want to navigate between different frames need to go back to Main frame first and then child. So the need to edit the src would not be needed.

This will take you to main frame and then child frame

```
 Driver.SwitchTo().DefaultContent()
                    Driver.SwitchTo().Frame("frameMain")
```

Driver.SwitchTo().Frame("framePage")